# Oracle tools not available on Visual Studio 2019 Community edition

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, odac

I have a VS 2019 Commujnity project targeting .NET core 5.
Over VS 2019, I’ve installed Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2019  ODT for VS 2019 19.3.3.0.0;
On my project, I’ve installed Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 3.21.80 via NuGet.
My problem is that on Toolbox I don’t see Oracle Tab.

I’ve tried to manually create Oracle tab by adding OracleCommand, OracleCommandBuilder, OracleConnection, OracleDataAdapter all from Oracle.ManagedDataAccess assembly.

The problem is that the "Choose Toolbox Items" show me only ".NET Framework components" and not something like ".NET Core components": maybe I've choosen wrong items.

So I still have problem, when I try to drag an OracleDataAdapter the wizard don’t start.

Any suggestion?...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, unfortunatelly it isn't something related to code. My problem is related to how ODAC works with Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Core. My questions: are there anybody that works with ODAC on Visual Studio and .Net Core/WinForms? Does wizard  work for OracleDataAdapter on a .NET Core WInForms app? When I drag this adapter from toolbox to a WinForms editor nothing happens. But on a .NET Framework/WInForms  app, this wizard starts as expected.